# How to parse this json with multiple objects

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

devs I am stuck in parsing this kind of JSON I don't understand how to get the value of status and message any help will be very appreciable. I get the value of error but when I want to access the value of status and message it throws an error
JSON Format :

```js
{
    "error": {
        "status": 400,
        "message": "Wrong number of segments"
    }
}
```

My code for parsing json :

```js
  try {
                    JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));

                    //jso.getJSONObject("error").getJSONObject("message");
                   jso.getJSONObject("error");
                   jso.getJSONObject("status").toString(200);
                    Log.d(TAG,"jso1"+jso);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: First you need to learn how to Parse a json response.

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/android-json-parsing-tutorial Try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jso = (JSONObject) parser.parse(String.valueOf(response));
```

The above command will give you the response as JSON.

To get Status and message, you need to extract error as a separate JSONObject and then parse status and message

```
JSONObject errorObj = (JSONObject) jso.get("error");
String message = errorObj.get("message").toString();
int status = Integer.parseInt(errorObj.get("status").toString());
```

Remember to parse and retrieve using the hierarchy.. so if the status & message are inside "error", then extract error as a JSONObject and then retrieve the child keys. And as a good practice check if the key exists or not:-

```
if(errorObj.has("")) {
// do something
}
```

**Adding a working sample** :-

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser; 
private static void parseJsonTest() {
            String json = "{\n" +
                    "    \"error\": {\n" +
                    "        \"status\": 400,\n" +
                    "        \"message\": \"Wrong number of segments\"\n" +
                    "    }\n" +
                    "}";
            try {
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    
                JSONObject jso = (JSONObject) parser.parse(json);
    
                JSONObject errorObj = (JSONObject) jso.get("error");
                String message = errorObj.get("message").toString();
                int status = Integer.parseInt(errorObj.get("status").toString());
    
                System.out.println(message + " >>>>>>> " + status);
            } catch (Exception e) {
    
            }
        }
```

Output :-

```
Wrong number of segments >>>>>>> 400
```

Comment: Ok it is very helpful but when I want to access the value of error it gives an error unable to convert string into jsonobject

Comment: Areu using JSON(org.json.simple.JSONObject) or GSON

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
                JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));

                //jso.getJSONObject("error").getString("message");
               jso.getJSONObject("error");
               jso.getJSONObject("error").getInt("status"); // if it was string use getString or it was int than use value getInt
                Log.d(TAG,"jso1"+jso);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
try {
                    JSONObject fullResponse = new SONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                    JSONObject errorData = fullResponse.getJSONObject("error");
                    String errorCode = errorData.getObject("status");
                    String errorMessage = errorData.getString("message");                  
                    Log.d(TAG,"Result = "+errorCode +" - "+errorMessage );
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

the Best way to convert Json to java it's to use converters libraries such as Gson
check the link below :

https://github.com/google/gson